# Outlook add-in: action to hide Taskpane

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

There is an action to show Task pane, specified in manifest:

```xml
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
</Action>
```

But is it possible to hide it from code?

Comment: [Show or hide the task pane of your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in) could help in what are you thinking

Answer (score 1):

[Office.context.ui.closeContainer](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.closecontainer?product=outlook) could work for your case.