# Can an outlook (Javascript) add-in be displayed as a dialog and not a taskpane?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I currently have an Outlook addin (REST/Javascript) that gets displayed as a taskpane at the right hand side of the window whenever Outlook is opened. And I show a dialog window whenever I want to emphasize a message to the user via [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

A recent desired feature however, made me think if it is possible for my Outlook (Javascript) addin to just show itself as a dialog, without any right hand side taskpane. Or we can still continue with what we have (a taskpane and a dialog) but set the taskpane hidden/invisible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in for hiding taskpane and this stackoverflow post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929033/outlook-add-in-action-to-hide-taskpane

Comment: Thank you @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT. I have seen these docs but was unsure whether they apply to what I do. Let me try them out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add a button for your addin which can directly open display dialog. Please look at how an ui-less action command can be implemented in Outlook Addins. You can refer to "FunctionFile" documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile) and also "Executing a Javascript function" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook#executing-a-javascript-function).

Comment: Thank you @Outlook Addins team. I have read the documentation and the changes required to get this done. And I believe this is the right way to go. Unfortunately, after several deliberations, we decided to proceed with another approach. Thank you again.